# My menu items are not being colored completely

Tags: html, css, flexbox, padding, bootstrap-5

I am using bootstrap 5. The color is working properly for background but I think something is wrong with that too but right now my main problem is that the menu buttons are not being colored completely. Only the middle part of them is colored and not the paddings. i have tried using background-clip but that is also not working.

HTML

```
<div class="theme-bg offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasLeft" aria-labelledby="offcanvasLeftLabel" style="background-color: #7bed9f;">
    <div class="offcanvas-header justify-content-end">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close text-reset" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-header d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        <img class="profile mb-2" src="{% static 'images/profile-default.png' %}">
        <h2 class="text-center ">Welcome Saif</h2>
    </div>
    <hr class="m-0">
    <div class="offcanvas-body p-0 container-fluid list-group list-group-flush border-bottom">
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between container-fluid theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-home me-1"></i> Home </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-search me-1"></i> Search </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-pencil me-1"></i> Write your blog </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-briefcase me-1"></i> Portfolio </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-gear me-1"></i> Settings </p>
            </div>
        </a>
        <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-3 lh-tight">
            <div class="d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between theme-bg">
                <p class="mb-1 fs-6"><i class="fa fa-sign-out me-1"></i> Sign Out </p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.theme-bg {
    background-color: #7bed9f;
   padding: 0px;
    background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

the menu items aren't colored completely

[image]

Comment: Why are you applying the background-color to those inner div elements, and not the links themselves?

Comment: Btw., that's rather "ugly" code for a navigation. Why are those link texts wrapped in  _paragraphs_? Why is this not a _list_ of links to begin with? At least the latter has been state of the art for I'd say at least a decade now.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I definitely do think you should go back to the original Bootstrap 5 Nav code (link) and starting again. Yes `.theme-bg` should be on the `a` tags.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navbar/

Comment: guys I tried putting .theme-bg on a tags but that ain't working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Remove all padding from your `list-group-item` elements (you can do this by giving them a class of `p-0`)
2. Add your padding to the direct child (`d-flex w-100 align-items-center justify-content-between container-fluid theme-bg`)

That did it for me, hope it helps :)